# Is there an ISO standard for cameras recording date taken?

Tags: exif, image-processing

My application has a set of images on which computation is conducted. But the issue is that most of the cameras that take the images do not provide seconds in the "Date Taken" field of the image properties.

For example: Date Taken of an image is shown as "23/1/2012 22:12" but they do not provide seconds in "hh:mm:ss".
Is there any ISO standard to which all comply?

Comment: Sorry, is the issue the camera doesn't record time in seconds as this may be considered off topic here. When you take a copy of your photo onto your computer it only has access to what is available.

Comment: I am asking if there is any norm that camera's follow and do not record seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EXIF standard](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) states the datetime is ASCI `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`.

Use an exif viewer to determine whether the seconds are genuinely missing, or whether it is just the image viewer you are using chooses not to display the seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I absolutely did that. The seconds are missing from the images. If this continues, I will have to ask the client to check camera settings

Comment: I haven't seen an option to exclude seconds in a date in camera settings, so it may be that a different camera is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at dates that are actually stamped on the picture itself?  Because you can right click on a file in windows explorer and goto properties and the details tab will tell you when that image was taken including time.  I don't know of an iso standard for that, wasn't able to find anything on it but I'll imagine there's some sort of standard set of rules but if you use my method that won't matter I don't think because all pictures will have that info attached I believe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is in the above you mentioned, that the seconds are missing. Hence asked :)